# Replicating our corp serv TFS source control in AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, replication, tfs-2015

Hi my corp is trying to move everything into AWS however we have a corporate TFS that we check our code into which probably won't change anytime soon. We are on the latest TFS release. Is it possible to have a TFS setup where a developer checks code into the corporate TFS repo locally and it gets replicated in a TFS source control in AWS? Are there better solutions for this like checking into corporate TFS which then sends the checked in file to AWS GIT repo? Just looking for any solutions to this that someone may have encountered at their company. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replication is not a supported feature of TFS.  They do have proxies for improving latency of big files for remote teams but this is different.

TFS uses SQL Server to store its data so in theory you may be able to get this working with SQL replication but I've never seen or heard of a working example.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take that into account and see what I can do!